# How to show $\|Pf\|_{L^1(\mathbb T^n)}\leq \|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb T^n)}$:

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

I need some help with the following problem: Let $P:S(\mathbb R^n)\rightarrow C^\infty(\mathbb T^n)$ be the operator given by $f\mapsto Pf$ where, $$Pf(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n} f(x+k).$$ How can I show $\|Pf\|_{L^1(\mathbb T^n)}\leq \|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^n)}$. Here $S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the Schwartz space and $\displaystyle\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb T^n)}=\int_{\mathbb T^n}|f(x)|\ dx$. I've spent a lot time on it and I got nowhere.. Thanks

Comment: If you expand $\|Pf\|_1$, you should get sums of integrals, did you try shifting the bounds from the torus to other disjoint rectangles of $R^N$ using a change of variable? (The goal is to convert to a single integral of $f$)

Comment: No I hadn't tried that yet...Thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifying the torus $\mathbb{T}^n$ with $Q=[0,1)^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, we have for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}^n$:
$$
\|\tau_kf\|_{L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)}=\int_{Q}|f(x+k)|\,dx=\int_{k+Q}|f|,
$$
where
$$
(\tau_kf)(x)=f(x+k) \quad \forall x,k \in \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
and 
$$
k+Q=[k_1,1+k_1)\times\ldots\times[k_n,1+k_n) \quad \forall k=(k_1,\ldots,k_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n.
$$
Since
$$
\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{z}^n}(k+Q)=\mathbb{R}^n,
$$
it follows that
$$
\|Pf\|_{L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)}=\left\|\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n}\tau_kf\right\|_{L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)}\le \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n}\|\tau_kf\|_{L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)}= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n}\int_{k+Q}|f|=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|=\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, that was a lot instructive =D